# Permission issue with Nuget?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I was trying to install a Nuget package and encountered the following error:

> [nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
>   An error occurred while sending the request.
>   Unable to connect to the remote server
>
> **An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 72.21.81.200:443**

I do **not** have an HTTP proxy setup, and I've never seen this error before.  Does anyone know what this is and how to fix it?  Using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.

Comment: Just installed a new antivirus or something? check your firewall if there's any blocking rule

Answer (score 0):

> Permission issue with Nuget?

For error “An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions”, you may try below suggestions:

1. Disable Windows Firewall temporarily.
2. Disable anti-virus software temporarily.
3. Using CMD command “netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt” to reset TCP/IP.
4. Re-start problematic system.

If above suggestion not resolve this issue, please try to check this issue with other network or PC. This issue should be more related to permission of the Network/PC.

Hope this helps.